How come java.time.zone.ZoneRules requires to generate timezone transitions?
In java 21 (available since java 8) there's a static factory method java.time.zone.ZoneRules#of which is the suggested way to create custom timezone definitions that would later be provided via ZoneRulesProvider. The method accepts 5 parameters, as follows:

baseStandardOffset - offset used for dates that predate the rules set
baseWallOffset - wall offset for dates that predate the rules set
standardOffsetTransitionList - list of changes to the standard offset
transitionsList - list of transitions for given time zone
lastRules - up to 16 recurring rules that algorithmically define transitions

Given that it permits providing algorithmic rules that would generate the next transition after a given date, how come the transitions list parameter is still mandatory? For example, given the following snippet that would create a DST zone which transitions from +02 to +03 on march 1st or earliest sunday afterwards, and from +03 to +02 on septembter 1st or earliest sunday afterwards. Imports omitted for brevity
    LocalDateTime startOfDst = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 3, 1, 3, 0);
    LocalDateTime endOfDst = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 9, 1, 3, 0);
    int summerOffset = 3;
    int winterOffset = 2;
    ZoneOffset winterZoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(winterOffset);
    ZoneOffset summerZoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(summerOffset);
    ZoneOffsetTransitionRule winterOffsetRule = ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.of(
            endOfDst.getMonth(),
            endOfDst.getDayOfMonth(),
            DayOfWeek.SUNDAY,
            endOfDst.toLocalTime(),
            false,
            TimeDefinition.UTC,
            winterZoneOffset,
            summerZoneOffset,
            winterZoneOffset
    );
    ZoneOffsetTransitionRule summerOffsetRule = ZoneOffsetTransitionRule.of(
            startOfDst.getMonth(),
            startOfDst.getDayOfMonth(),
            DayOfWeek.SUNDAY,
            startOfDst.toLocalTime(),
            false,
            TimeDefinition.UTC,
            winterZoneOffset,
            winterZoneOffset,
            summerZoneOffset
    );
    ZoneRules rules = ZoneRules.of(
            winterZoneOffset,
            winterZoneOffset,
            Collections.emptyList(),
            Collections.emptyList(),
            Arrays.asList(summerOffsetRule, winterOffsetRule)
    );

With the given configuration calling rules.nextTransition(Instant.now()) produces null, because in the underlying rules object the savingsInstantTransitions field is not initialized (read: has length of zero, see snippet below), because the transitionsList parameter was provided as an empty collection.
public ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition(Instant instant) {
    if (savingsInstantTransitions.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ...
}

Meanwhile, the field is only being initialized if the transitionsList parameter has at least one value, as seen by this constructor snippet
ZoneRules(ZoneOffset baseStandardOffset,
          ZoneOffset baseWallOffset,
          List<ZoneOffsetTransition> standardOffsetTransitionList,
          List<ZoneOffsetTransition> transitionList,
          List<ZoneOffsetTransitionRule> lastRules) {
    super();
    ...
    // convert savings transitions to instants
    this.savingsInstantTransitions = new long[transitionList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < transitionList.size(); i++) {
        this.savingsInstantTransitions[i] = transitionList.get(i).toEpochSecond();
    }
    ...

Shouldn't it be possible to generate a timezone without a transition history? How do you properly define a custom timezone?

My guess is that it might be expecting you to pass at least the transition from baseWallOffset to baseStandardOffset.

@Sweeper that might be the case. The zone rules still have to go "into effect" at some point in time.
